# Show image in Image View by retrieving URI from table

Tags: android

I am taking image from gallery and save it to SQLite database but when i retrieve it it gives me error at this line

```
  tvimg.setImageURI(Uri.parse(((c.getString(3)))));
```

It also shows error despite of adding permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Logcat**

> Unable to open content: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A150033
>                                                                        java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{e822ff6 3865:com.example.yuser.samajapp/u0a220} (pid=3865, uid=10220) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

I am unable to get understand what is wrong with this code..

Comment: what error are you getting show us logcat

Comment: Unable to open content: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A150033 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{e822ff6 3865:com.example.yuser.samajapp/u0a220} (pid=3865, uid=10220) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

Comment: are you testing your app marshmellow or above.. ? then you need to ask permission programitically

Comment: when i am inserting it into table or show image from passing URI through Intent this URI working but when i am retrieving it from table it is not working

Comment: add this permission in manifest `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`

Comment: already added this permission..still not working

Comment: first test your app on lollipop or lower

Comment: got the solution by adding permission programmaticly..thank you so much